# Default Processes?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applications

What are the default processes that would run in a freshly installed copy of Lion? I want to know which ones that I have are third-party processes so I can remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Thre are many and it depends what you are running and I suspect changes from minor version to another so there is no definitive list.

In a terminal type `ps auxwwww` to list all the processes.

This command includes the full path - from this you can see which are Apple ones in/System /usr/bin, /bin , Then look at each one running from /Applications